# Delete pointer in two lists

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have an array of linked list , each index of  array holds linked list.

Beside that, I have another linked list , that hold nodes in exact order I inputted them.

So for example.
My array has 500 indexes. I input one node on index 1 and one node on index 2.
When I print linked list on index 1 it will print only one node. However when I print the linked list that holds the exact order that node were inputted in , it will print both of them in order I inputted them.

I have implemented this using this code

```
class CHash{

public:
    CHash(){
        for( int i = 0; i < 500 ;i++){
            holder[i] = NULL;
        }
        first = NULL;
        last  = NULL;
    };
    void insert( string key , string value ){
        size_t num = index(key);
        Node *tmp;
        if( holder[num] == NULL ){
            tmp = new Node(key , value , NULL);
            holder[num] = tmp;
        }else{
            tmp = new Node(key, value , holder[num]);
            holder[num] = tmp;
        }
        if( first == NULL){
            tmp -> nextNode = NULL;
            tmp -> prevNode = NULL;
            first = tmp;
            last  = tmp;
        }else{
            tmp -> prevNode = last;
            last -> nextNode = tmp;
            last = tmp;
        }
    }
    void Print( size_t number ){
        Node *tmp = holder[number];
        while( tmp!= NULL){
            cout << tmp -> value << endl;
            tmp = tmp -> next;
        }
    }
    void PrintAll(){
        Node *tmp = first;
        while( tmp != NULL){
            cout << tmp -> value << endl;
            tmp = tmp -> nextNode;
        }
    }
    size_t index( string name ){
        return name.length();
    }
    void de(string val){
        size_t num = index(val);
        if( holder[num] == NULL){
            return;
        }
         Node *tmp = holder[num];
         Node *help;
         Node *help1;
        while( tmp != NULL){
            if( tmp -> key == val){
                Node *temp = tmp;
                if( tmp -> prevNode != NULL)
                    help = tmp -> prevNode;
                else
                          help = NULL;
                if( tmp -> nextNode != NULL)
                    help1 = tmp -> nextNode;
                else
                          help1 = NULL;
                if( tmp -> next != NULL){
                    tmp = tmp -> next;
                    tmp -> nextNode = help1;
                    tmp -> prevNode = help;
                }
                else
                    tmp = NULL;

                delete temp;
                return ;
            }
            tmp = tmp -> next;
        }
    }
```

It works , what troubles me is the `de` method. It should find the node with key same as argument and delete it. This delete should be reflected in both linked list. I have been trying to figure this out for a while but it always throw seg fault.

Example of usage.

```
 CHash one;
    one.insert("two","cauko");
    one.insert("tuk","hello");
    one.insert("three","hrello");
    one.Print(3) // should print "hello" , "cauko"
    one.PrintAll() // should print "cauko" , "hello" , "hrello"
    one.de("tuk");
    one.Print(3); // should print only "cauko"
    one.PrintAll(); // should print "cauko" , "hrello"
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Imagine if you had a large code base, and wanted to search for all instances of `de`.  What I'm saying is that you should give your functions a little bit more of a descriptive name.

Comment: Why not use `std::list` instead of all of this linked list code?  Or at the very least, create a working standalone linked list class without hash table code.  Once it works, *then* you use that working, debugged, linked list class in your larger hash table program.  BTW, I don't see an array of linked list -- I would have expected `LinkedList allLists[5];`' or something like that -- that is an array of linked lists.

Comment: `        if( holder[num] == NULL ){            tmp = new Node(key , value , NULL);            holder[num] = tmp;        }else{            tmp = new Node(key, value , holder[num]);            holder[num] = tmp;        }`. Redundant code much?

Answer (score 3):

You should give a more explicit name to the `de` function, add comments, create more functions for individual tasks like finding the node for a specific value and give a fully compilable code.

The code below for `de` assumes that the linked list using `->next` doesn't have a corresponding `prev`, as no information is given on this subject.

```
void deleteVal(string val){
    size_t num = index(val);
    if( holder[num] == NULL){
        return;
    }

    /* Find the key first */
    Node* tmp = holder[num];
    Node *prev = NULL;
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        if (tmp->key == val) {
            break;
        }
        prev = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    if (tmp->key != val) {
        //key not found
        return;
    }

    /* remove the element from the global linked list */
    if (tmp->prevNode) {
        tmp->prevNode->nextNode = tmp->nextNode;
    }
    if (tmp->nextNode) {
        tmp->nextNode->prevNode = tmp->prevNode;
    }

    if (first == tmp) {
        first = tmp->nextNode;
    }
    if (last == tmp) {
        last = tmp->prevNode;
    }

    /* Now remove the element from the linked list corresponding to index */
    if (holder[num] == tmp) {
        holder[num] = tmp->next;
    } else {
        prev->next = tmp->next;
    }
//uncomment if the ->prev member exists in your class
//     if (tmp->next) tmp->next->prev = tmp->prev;
    /* Delete. */
    delete tmp; //maybe tmp->next = tmp->nextNode = NULL before depending on your destructor
}
```

The main problem was that you were mixing the two linked lists here in your code:

```
            if( tmp -> next != NULL){
                tmp = tmp -> next;
                tmp -> nextNode = help1;
                tmp -> prevNode = help;
            }
```

The two linked lists have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Thanks , this does not throw seg fault , but code that demonstrate usage of it. using printAll after delete prints the first value twice.

Comment: I edited to add updating of `first` and `last` if needed. To help any further I'd need to have a whole code compilable (full file for `CHash` and `Node`)

Answer (score 1):

> I have an array of linked list , each index of array holds linked list.
>
> Beside that, **I have another linked list** , that hold nodes in exact order I inputted them.

You shouldn't have nodes shared between these linked lists, unless you're using something like

```
struct Node {
    // ...
    std::shared_ptr<Node> prev_node;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> next_node;
};
```

Also have a look at [What is the Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to manage two interwoven linked lists, and you are shredding them both. **You must master simpler exercises before you attempt something this complex.**

Specifically, the problem is here:

```
if( tmp -> next != NULL){
  tmp = tmp -> next;
  tmp -> nextNode = help1;
  tmp -> prevNode = help;
}
else
tmp = NULL;
```

You completely neglect the node whose `next` points to `tmp`. And instead of connecting two nodes to each other by means of `help` and `help1` (your variable names are dreadful), you are connecting them both to an *unrelated node*.